# External speakers not getting sound Ubuntu Studio

Tags: nvidia, sound

I've been troubleshooting this for a while now. I'm not new to Linux but haven't had to do a lot of "deep" diving into troubleshooting.

Ubuntu Studio was 20.01 but just upgraded to 2.04 and problem followed.

Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-48-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe

I have a 3060 TI NVidia card (which I suspect is the problem)

The external speakers are connected to my monitor, works on windows and used to work on my Linux build but quit after one of the updates late last year.

I suspect I need to tell it to use the video card not the MB but can't find that setting anywhere!

Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Added later;
I tried to add a couple pics but I don't have enough "points" so they put a link instead.
One is the Audio settings screenshot, the other is what I believe is referred to the PAVU (Pulse Audio Settings)

I can see in the Audio settings it sees the card but the only option in there is OFF it won't allow me to turn it on.
In pulse audio settings it doesn't even show on any dropdowns

This is a pic of my desktop showing both above descriptions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keBTx.jpg)

Comment: Please check your details; Ubuntu's main products use a *year.month* format, so your 20.01 represents 2020-January (2000 is added to the *year*) but no release existed then, so 20.01 is incorrect.  You upgraded to 20.04 but then give details of 22.04 (*or a release of two years later*).  For useful advice, we need accurate details.

Comment: My mistake, I did install 20.01 and it was working until an update, then it quit working. So I upgraded to 22.04 which are the details you see now.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.01 (2020-January), there was a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (2020-April) and Ubuntu 20.10 (2020-October) release; but 20.10 was intended to upgrade to 21.04, and an upgrade from 20.04 (to 22.04) is *unexpected* as involves a desktop change and was thus unsupported (*breakage was to be expected*) which is why documentation said to re-install.  What release you were using matters.

Comment: Please read https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/ or "*Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported.*"

Comment: Appreciat4e your time all but seeing as I still don't have sound I'm going to go with another distro. I hate to leave Ubuntu but seems there was really no support. 
I think if we want more people to get off the MS addiction we have to make things more plain.
Good luck here

Comment: Ohhh and it was difficult to remember WHICH version was the old one for those of us that only just installed it... I know versions matter but without any record of it, it was my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think 3060 TI NVidia card  is the problem. The graphics is shown *llvmpipe* because linux does not play nice with nvidia devices. You would need to install the drivers and update your kernel. However in these cases for audio issues I would suggest first to take through pavucontrol packag from the main repositories. There you can check the **Output Devices** tab and see whether it is recognized by Ubuntu your audio device.

Comment: I didn't think it was either and it works great in windows (have 2 separate SSDs on comp)
I suspect it's something like you mentioned but I don't know where to update the driver and turn it on basically.
I've just updated the description and put a pic of my desktop with both the settings screens,
Thanks for the reply